# Automatic units of measure conversion in F# (kilometers -> meters)

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

It would be great to be able to auto-convert units of measure, which are just multipliers of the same dimension. (kg -> g, cm -> mm, km -> m). From what I've read online:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/

I doesn't seem possible to have this working without helper functions. From my view, those conversions pollute the computations. I want something like this to work:

```
[<Measure>] type m
[<Measure>] type km = 1000 * m
```

The below wouldn't work either.

```
let distance = 1000 * 10**3 <m>
```

Is this achievable in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know F#, but yeah, units polute computations. That's why you should convert values only during input (eg. reading form file/stdin), do calculations always in the same units, metric system is a go in here. Then, at the end, convert the result from metric system to whatever unit you want.

That way it's very easy to add support for new unit later on

Comment: the problem comes when you "assume" that everything is in the same unit but in the end it turns out not to be the case.... units of measure are great, they should be used more often

Comment: No, I want to my code to read as prose. F# is good at it. In this particular problem, I want to declare the inputs and computations without unnecessary trivial conversions. Same as I would do on a piece of paper.

Comment: on piece of paper you would not do this distance thing from your question. You would do speed = distance / time and that always gives you speed, but in different units based on the units of distance and speed. For my understanding, F# will do exactly the same. So what is your problem?

Comment: I don't think I would have the actual calculation on my paper. At least the one I'd present to someone. It's the implementation detail nobody cares about. We are discussing a declarative language, aren't we? Inputs, formula and result. Excel is happy to represent a fraction as % and use it in calculations. Having declared the relation between meters and kilometers as above is enough for the machine to do its work. Seems like this feature is missing. Subjective opinion like "you shouldn't need that" is not a great answer. It's as good as saying "you shouldn't need F#, since there is C#".